# Using the Selenium framework, how can I execute processes in existing tabs?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

**Task**: Execute 2 processes in 2 different tabs located in the same window, which are already opened.

**Query**: How can I execute the processes in tabs already created rather than opening new window?

**Code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
about = driver.find_element_by_link_text('About')
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(about).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")

def func1():
    while True:
        driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.get("https://www.google.com")
        time.sleep(1)

def func2():
    while True:
        driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.get("https://store.google.com/?srp=/product/google_home")
        time.sleep(1)
if __name__=='__main__':
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    p1 = Process(target = func1)
    p1.start()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    p2 = Process(target = func2)
    p2.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my research, I was able to find that you will have to have previous "Operating Systems" knowledge to get this to work. It is a browser specific task, which the Selenium team did not implement.

[Github Issue: on running tasks on existing tabs](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/18)